# Redirecting stdout to terminal and file without using a pipe?

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe

I have code, that goes something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR=0

func() {
    VAR=$((VAR+1))
    echo 'Logging information.'
}

func 2>&1 | tee 'log.txt'

echo "Should be 1: ${VAR}"
```

When calling it this happens:

```
:~$ ./script.sh
Should be 1: 0
```

As far as I understand it, this is because the pipe I'm using is spawning a subshell. The changes to `VAR` in there are not propagated up and therefore are not reflected in the output.

`func` in my case is a rather lengthy process and the output would need to be in real time. So just writing to a file and then `cat`ing the file is not an option. Also I would like to avoid writing anything to file and later reading it back in as a Variable if possible.

So is there any way to get the need for the pipe out of there, or a bash trick I don't know yet, that could help me?

EDIT:

Tried with a named pipe:

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR=0

func() {
        VAR=$((VAR+1))
        echo 'Logging information.'
        sleep 5
}

mkfifo my_fifo

func >my_fifo 2>&1 &

tee 'log .txt' <my_fifo

echo "Should be 1: ${VAR}"
```

Result is unfortunately the same:

```
:~$ ./script.sh
Should be 1: 0
```

Comment: Run the `tee < my_fifo` in background instead of your function in the second case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
func > >(tee log.txt) 2>&1
wait
```

You can dedicate a file descriptor for logging:

```
exec 3> >(tee log.txt)
tee_pid=$!

func >&3 2>&1
...
```

Beware though that as that `tee` runs in background, if not all the output goes through it, then the order in the output may be affected.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a tmp file

```
func >tmpfile 2>&1
tee 'log.txt' <tmpfile
```

or a FIFO

```
mkfifo pipe_replacement
tee 'log.txt' <pipe_replacement &
func >pipe_replacement 2>&1
```

Comment: Am I correct in that the first one would not output to the terminal in real time? I added that requirement to the question. I don't quite understand the second one. I'll read up, but if you could elaborate a bit what happens, then that would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Minix A FIFO is a special file that is used to connect processes, quite similar to a pipeline. The main differences are that a FIFO must be explicitly deleted and it is visible to all processes i.e. could be used by all. Give it a try.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. But unfortunately it is still the same result. I couldn't find a definitive word on the internet, if named pipes spawn subshells, too. But I would suspect they do based on the result.

Comment: @Minix The FIFO isn't the problem – the subshell caused by running in the background is... I changed the order so that `func` can run in the foreground. Try that.

Comment: mkfifo is super useful to use for Jenkins. Using a pipe will "misreport" the exit status and the PID and create issues with Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

I would do like...

```
#!/bin/sh -x
run() if ! ps -p "$run" >&2
      then n=0 run=$$ exec "$0" "$@" 2>&1 | {
         ! tee outfile ; }
      fi 2>/dev/null
run "$@" || exit

fn() { var=val$n; echo "$((n+=1)): $var"; }
fn 
sleep 5
fn
IN
```

That first checks if it's already got an open pipe to a `tee` in another process, and, if not, it `exec`s itself into one. After that all output is piped out for the rest of the script, and all variables set between then and the script exit are maintained - which is, in fact, how it does the check in the first place.

So, running the above prints:

```
+ run
+ run
+ fn
+ var=val0
+ echo 1: val0
1: val0
+ sleep 5
+ fn
+ var=val1
+ echo 2: val1
2: val1
+ exit
```

And running `cat outfile` afterward prints...

```
+ run
+ run
+ fn
+ var=val0
+ echo 1: val0
1: val0
+ sleep 5
+ fn
+ var=val1
+ echo 2: val1
2: val1
+ exit
```

You might also consider using `sed` as opposed to `tee`. While `tee` will be more performant for an *all-output* case, `sed` can write to many files at once, and can do so conditionally.

For example, you might echo a line like:

```
echo 'LOG-ONLY: some message here'
```

And a listening `sed` process could do:

```
sed -n '/^LOG-ONLY:/!p;s///w ./my_log.txt'
```

...which would `w`rite that line to a file after stripping the `LOG_ONLY` part and refrain from printing it to the terminal.